# "Sum" of probabilities equals infinity

Tags: probability, summation, divergent-series

We have some independent trials with a certain chance of succeeding, say the $t$th trial succeeds with probability $p(t)$, and fails with probability $1-p(t)$.  My question is, if the sum of probabilites diverges, i.e.

$$\sum_{t=1}^\infty{p(t)} = \infty$$

can we say that at least one trial will succeed almost always?

Comment: If they are independent, yes, in fact you can say infinitely many trials succeed almost surely. Search for “second Borel-Cantelli lemma”